# Swift framework with a plist

Tags: ios, swift

I have been developing a framework on Swift. The framework class has to access a plist file (appConfig.plist). The appConfig.plist file is placed in the root directory of the framework project.

This is the code I use.

```
        let bundle = Bundle(for: MyFramework.self)
        if let plistPath = bundle.path(forResource: "appConfig", ofType: "plist"),
           let plistData = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: plistPath) {
            do {
                let plistContents = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: plistData, options: [], format: nil)
                print(plistContents)
                Logger.shared.log(log:"Plist file found.")

            } catch {
                Logger.shared.log(log:"Error reading plist: \(error)")
            }
        } else {
            Logger.shared.log(log:"Plist file not found.")
        }
```

But the plist is not able to access the main project. When printed the bundle, it was "*</private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/873A28A5-C8EC-46B0-9606-A458D82AFE2F/Testapp.app>"*.

What could be the issue that the plist is not able to access?

Comment: Which step is failing, and what error are you getting?

Comment: I bet you're getting a file not found error. I suggest right-clicking the app on your Mac from the finder, selecting "Show package contents", and navigating to the plist file you are looking for. Then drag that file into a terminal window and note the path shown in Terminal. It is probably in a sub-directory of your app's bundle.